# Did Dutch ever have a G like in Garden sound?

Tags: phonology, dutch

In Modern Dutch I do not see or hear any hard G sound. Garden would be pronounced like Harden.. how did that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is generally held that in proto-Germanic, [g] and [γ] are in an allophonic relation, likewise [b,d] and [β,ð], similar to the situation in Spanish. Word-initially, the stops [b,d] are posited as positional variants. However, the North Sea Germanic languages including Dutch maintained the fricative pronunciation [γ] initially, though other languages developed stops across the board. The fricative allophone was ultimately lost in English, but Dutch retained the fricative – thus Dutch preserved an older phonetic value for the voiced velar obstruent. That does not mean that there was no phonetic [g] in proto-Germanic, indeed it is assumed that the *b,d,g* were stops post-nasally.

Comment: Despite what Ringe says, it’s not my impression that Proto-Germanic /g/ is _generally_ held to have been [ɣ] initially. Outside some of Ingvaeonic, I’m not aware of any actual evidence for this claim – Ringe does not give any further evidence either. The more Occamous option, that fricativisation of /g/ into [ɣ] initially was a later change within Ingvaeonic, has always been the default position in my experience. (And of course some dialects of Dutch, mainly those found in Frisian-adjacent areas, do have initial [g] nowadays, though that may well be a later development, I don’t know.)